# $geoNear for a list embeded locations and return distance for all location in list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an `user` collection:

```py
{
    "name": "David",
    "age": 20,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "radius": 10000,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [106.785299, 20.999999]
            }
        },
        {
            "radius": 30000,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [105.785299, 20.979733]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Each user will have one or more address. I want to calculate the distance between these addresses with a point, then using calculated distance to compare with radius of each address. If distance < radius then keep address else remove address from `addresses` list. I am using below query:

```py
db.collection.aggregrate(
    {
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 105.823620, 21.006047 ]},
            "distanceField": "distance",
            "key": "addresses.location"
        }
    }
)
```

But this query only return the distance of nearest address, like this:

```py
{
    "name": "David",
    "age": 20,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "radius": 10000,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [105.785299, 20.979733]
            }
        },
        {
            "radius": 30000,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [105.785299, 20.979733]
            }
        }
    ],
    "distance": 110000 // <--- distance is added here, just for nearest addrest
}
```

My expected result:

```py
{
    "name": "David",
    "age": 20,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "radius": 10000,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [105.785299, 20.979733]
            },
            "distance": 2000``// <------ add distance here for each addesss`
        },
        {
            "radius": 30000,
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [105.785299, 20.979733]
            },
            "distance": 30000 // <------ add distance here for each addesss
        }
    ]
}
```

So next stage I can compare `distance` with `radius` and keep proper adddress
Anybody know how to do it ? thanks

Comment: Both addresses has the same coordinates, so distance is the same for both of them. You need to store 1 address 1 document, then `$geoNear` can calculate correctly your expected value. Then , you can group them into desired output

Comment: @Valijon, sorry, it's just a sample data. And of couse all addresses will have difference coordinate. I have fixed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store each address in an individual document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec77d127df107cd889d567d"),
    "name" : "David",
    "age" : 20,
    "addresses" : {
        "radius" : 10000,
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                105.785299, 
                20.979733
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec77f7843732e8f9a63bf67"),
    "name" : "David",
    "age" : 20,
    "addresses" : {
        "radius" : 30000,
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                105.795299, 
                20.989733
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we perform `$geoNear` and `$group` stages:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          105.823620,
          21.006047
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "distance",
      "key": "addresses.location"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "age": {
        "$first": "$age"
      },
      "addresses": {
        "$push": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$addresses",
            {
              "distance": "$distance"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: If store address in an individual document, It may create redundant data. But must we do this, then we can do `$geoNear`, right?

Comment: @PhùngXuânAnh Yes. We need to store it individually. Also, You can store coordinates individually in collection1, and user data in collection2. Then, we can perform `$lookup` stage to join them.